# np.where() has bug when handling zero element division in array

Tags: numpy, divide-by-zero

When i want to avoid the situation of zero encountered in divide, I used `np.where(a != 0, b / a, 0)` to judge this, and found a **RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide**. This is wired, beacase i do the same operation in pytorch with tensor, it has no warning emerged. The test code shows below. Can anyone tell me why numpy came out this warning but the result is correct, whereas worked fine in pytorch?

```py
a = torch.tensor([[[4, 0,], [4, 4]], [[3, 3,], [3, 3]]])
b = np.ones((2, 2, 2))
# print(a.shape)
b = torch.where(a != 0, b / a, 0)
print(b)

a = np.array([[[4, 0,], [4, 4]], [[3, 3,], [3, 3]]])
b = np.ones((2, 2, 2))
# print(a.shape)
b = np.where(a != 0, b / a, 0)
print(b)
```

and the results shows like blow:

```
tensor([[[0.2500, 0.0000],
         [0.2500, 0.2500]],

        [[0.3333, 0.3333],
         [0.3333, 0.3333]]], dtype=torch.float64)
private/test.py:77: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  b = np.where(a != 0, b / a, 0)
[[[0.25       0.        ]
  [0.25       0.25      ]]

 [[0.33333333 0.33333333]
  [0.33333333 0.33333333]]]
```

Comment: Where does **not** have a bug. When you run `torch.where(a != 0, b / a, 0)`, first `b/a` is evaluated, and only after `where`. You need to use the `where=…` in [`np.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html)!

Comment: With the tensors, does `b/a` by itself  produce the warning?

Comment: I get the impression that `torch` does not raise a runtimewarning for divide by zero.  This, and other web searchs, https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-divide-only-where-denominator-is-non-zero/133968, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751109/pytorch-when-divided-by-zero-set-the-result-value-with-0